# Function with the same argument does not return the same value

Tags: c, uint64

I was "playing" with the [fast inverse sqrt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root) function by trying to optimize certain things (fewer variables etc). Here is the final code:

```
float Q_rsqrt(float x) {
    const float x2 = x * 0.5F;
    uint_fast32_t i;
    memcpy(&i, &x, sizeof(float));
    i = 0x5f3759df - ( i >> 1 );
    memcpy(&x, &i, sizeof(float));
    return x * ( 1.5F - ( x2 * x * x ) );
}
```

First of all, it is useful to know that on my architecture `uint_fast32_t` is represented on 64 bits and `float` on 32 bits. It can therefore be surprising to make `memcpy()` on variable types of different sizes.
The problem I have once the code is compiled, a call to this function with the same argument each time gives the same return value : sometimes this one is negative, other times positive (but always of the same absolute value).
The usefulness of `memcpy()` is to bypass the warning (dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules) of the following code (which works exactly as desired) :

```
float Q_rsqrt_test(float x) {
    const float xHalf = x * 0.5F;
    const uint_fast32_t i = 0x5f3759df - ( (* ( uint_fast32_t * ) &x) >> 1 );
    x = * ( float * ) &i;
    return x * ( 1.5F - ( xHalf * x * x ) );
}
```

For this code, I want to say that there is no problem of type size because already the source (visible on the link just above) uses a `double type`, which is represented on 64 bits on my architecture (instead of `float` on 32 bits).

I really can't understand why I can get negative answers with the first function...

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're copying only 32 bits, the other 32 bits of `i` are uninitialized. So it can be different each time.

Comment: Try initializing `i = 0;` first.

Comment: using `uint32_t i` would be another solution

Comment: Ahhh it might be that... But if so, the dereferencing with the pointer `*(uint_fast32_t *) &x` should be "corrupted" no? I mean, this will take also 32 another bits after the float we want and thus, is dangerous because we don't know what are the 32 last bits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Barmar said, initializing i to 0 works. I also think it's better to avoid dereferecing to a type with another size (for example `*(uint64_t *) &x` where x is a float). Probably better using dereferecing with `uint32_t` and then properly cast the result to a 64 bits variable.